# fonts with equal weight and perfect circles

Tags: font-recommendation, serif

I am attempting to find a font that meets this criteria:

1. I need it to be geometrical (the circles in the lowercase "d" to be a perfect circle)
2. I want the fonts to be single weight throughout.  As in the where the shoulder of the lower case "d" meeting the stem, it does not narrow.  Same with the lowercase "n".  These are just example letters.

Should look like Helvetica, or Avenir.  Avenir has a perfect circles but the "n" narrows out.

Here is an example I found of a non-narrowing weight.  It should stay equal throughout.  As in the "same thickness."

There should be a ready-made font.  How do I search about such criteria?  Can I avoid using Illustrator correct the narrowing?

[image: example of round and no narrowing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you will like these fonts:

[Led Zeppelin2](http://www.dafont.com/zeppelin2.font)

[TPF Janus font](http://www.fontyukle.net/en/TPF+Janus.ttf)

[Josefin Sans](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Josefin-Sans)

[Sofia Pro](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/sofia-pro)

UPDATE

Sofia Pro has "imperfections" in the connecting arcs, that s true...

[image]

Comment: Sofia Pro was almost perfect until I noticed the shoulders on the "n" and the "m" do get narrower.

Comment: I don't mind paid fonts.  I just really need those arcs to not get narrow.

Answer (score 2):

Broadly speaking, you are looking for a '[geometric sans](http://www.myfonts.com/search/geometric+sans/fonts/)'.

They may not all have perfect circles, however. So you may have to dig through them to find the ones that will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried **Circular**?

[image]

Unfortunately it's not available on Typekit or Google Fonts, but it [can be downloaded from Lineto](https://lineto.com/The+Fonts/Font+Categories/Text+Fonts/Circular/).

It's popping up everywhere at the moment (Spotify just started using it across all of their apps), but it's a beautiful typeface.

Answer (score 0):

The font which leapt to my mind was [Futura.](http://store1.adobe.com/cfusion/store/html/index.cfm?store=OLS-US&event=displayFontPackage&code=1189)

Comment: A great typeface, but note that it doesn't have a lot of 'perfect' circles.

Comment: Are there "techniques" to alter then in Illustrator for perfect circles? Futura is nice indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ilan and DA01, seems like you need a geometric sans of some sort.

There are a couple free ones that came to mind, though I have not done any detailed comparisons on these:

- Josefin Sans (mentioned above)
- Montserrat

[Both are from Google Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts/#)

Comment: Monsterrat was really nice but the arcs on the "m" and the "n" do get narrow.  Is this easy to "mathematically" alter in Illustrator?